# kubernetes deployment notification to slack channel using webhook

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have set up the notification for cloud build CI/CD which is pushing notification to a respective slack channel.

After a successful build that image push to kubernetes cluster and rolling update strategy followed by deployment.

So I want to push notification when new pod become ready and old pod terminated so that time gets an idea about new changes applied to deployment.

**Note** : I am using GKE cluster but not installed Prometheus due to resource limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this, I can think of two ways right now:

1. Use Prometheus + Alert manager to send you a slack notification when pods became ready.
2. Use CI/CD pipeline to continuously check for the status of the pods, once they are updated successfully, send a notification.

Hope this answers your question.

EDIT:
If you would like to stick to using stackdriver, then there is a solution for it as well: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/events-stackdriver/

Comment: What kind of Prometheus query do I need to detect if my pod is ready?

Comment: Hi thank you for writing an answer but i have installed the Prometheus in a cluster. for monitoring, i am using default stack drvier of GCP.

Comment: As CI/CD i am using cloud build so it's hard to implement

Comment: @FL3SH I don't know the exact query, but you can have a look at this project: https://github.com/caicloud/event_exporter

Comment: I thought you can do it just with Prometheus.

Comment: @FL3SH i have not installed Prometheus agent due to memory limit.

Comment: @FL3SH Nah, you have to have an exporter.

Comment: @HarshManvar You can have a look at this link: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/observing#timeline for stackdriver.

Comment: Hey @HarshManvar! I actually found a better article: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/events-stackdriver/ I have also updated my answer. Hope this would help.

Comment: @Harith Thanks a lot perfect solution i think will implement and try it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @HarshManvar You have to search on how to alert based on the log events though.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot afford to Prometheus stack due to resources limitation check [kubewatch](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/kubewatch) it has slack support build-in so it should be suitable for your needs.

Comment: kubewatch is not working properly giving extra notification also tried to configuration using configmap. but not working as expected.

Comment: Yes but for all event or specific event we can use it kubewatch. Overall nice it is.

Answer (score 1):

Using kubernetes api watch can be implemented
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/tree/master/examples/watch

Basically it will check the not running pod and notify using Microsoft Teams web-hook. It will also notify pod which was initially not running and came back to running status again(recovered pod)

C# code snippet below with Main and Notify function.
You can replace the deployment over pod

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Load from the default kubeconfig on the machine.
            var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile();

            // Use the config object to create a client.
            var client = new Kubernetes(config);


            try
            {

                var podlistResp = await client.ListNamespacedPodWithHttpMessagesAsync(Namespace, watch: true);
                using (podlistResp.Watch<V1Pod, V1PodList>(async (type, item) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(type);
                    Console.WriteLine("==on watch event==");
                    var message = $"Namespace: {Namespace} Pod: {item.Metadata.Name} Type: {type}  Phase:{item.Status.Phase}";
                    var remessage = $"Namespace: {Namespace} Pod: {item.Metadata.Name} Type: {type} back to Phase:{item.Status.Phase}";
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    if (!item.Status.Phase.Equals("Running") && !item.Status.Phase.Equals("Succeeded"))
                    {   Console.WriteLine("==on watch event==");
                        await Notify(message);
                        Console.WriteLine("==on watch event==");
                    }
                    if ( type== WatchEventType.Modified && item.Status.Phase.Equals("Running") )
                    {   Console.WriteLine("==on watch event==");
                        await Notify(remessage);
                        Console.WriteLine("==on watch event==");
                    }
                }))
                {
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("press ctrl + c to stop watching");

                    var ctrlc = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
                    Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) => ctrlc.Set();
                    ctrlc.Wait();
                }
            }
            
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine($"An error happened Message: {ex.Message}", ex);
            }
        }

        private static async Task Notify(string message)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://outlook.office.com");
                var body = new { text = message };
                var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body));
                var result = await client.PostAsync("https://outlook.office.com/webhook/xxxx/IncomingWebhook/xxx", content);
                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Ranjita  thanks for writing an answer, i have used the same way, K8s api and written simple python code. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for such tool, do try [BotKube](https://www.botkube.io/). It is built to send
Kubernetes events to messengers like Slack, Mattermost and Microsoft Teams. It also has features like custom [filters](https://www.botkube.io/filters/)